# Invalid Column Name when using modelbuilder to create composite keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am using EF 6 and in an attempt to get around this error message:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

I read about this solution using modelbuilder in your dbcontext to create a composite key that seems to fix this issue: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/05/08/missing-ef-feature-workarounds-cascade-delete-orphans/ (not the post itself, the first comment)

Anyway, life was good I had a parent model with various children and everything was working like a dream until I tried to implement this with a child object that itself had children. Here is an abbreviated version of my model:

```
public class StateYear
{
    public long stateYearId { get; set; }
    public string year { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Plan> Plans { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ReportAssignment> ReportAssignments { get; set; }
}

public class Plan
{
    public long planId { get; set; }
    public long stateYearId { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual StateYear StateYear { get; set; }
}

public class ReportAssignment
{
    public long reportAssignmentId { get; set; }
    public long stateYearId { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual StateYear StateYear { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<McoPihpAssignment> McoPihpAssignments { get; set; }
}

public class McoPihpAssignment
{
    public long mcoPihpAssignmentId { get; set; }
    public long reportAssignmentId { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual ReportAssignment ReportAssignment { get; set; }
}
```

and I implemented the modelbuilder solution in my DbContext like so:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Plan>()
            .HasKey(a => new { a.planId, a.stateYearId});
        modelBuilder.Entity<Plan>()
            .Property(a => a.planId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ReportAssignment>()
            .HasKey(a => new { a.reportAssignmentId, a.stateYearId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<ReportAssignment>()
            .Property(a => a.reportAssignmentId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        modelBuilder.Entity<McoPihpAssignment>()
            .HasKey(a => new { a.mcoPihpAssignmentId, a.reportAssignmentId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<McoPihpAssignment>()
            .Property(a => a.mcoPihpAssignmentId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

However when I try to retrieve a StateYear record I get this error message:

> ```
>   Message=Invalid column name 'ReportAssignment_reportAssignmentId'. 
>   Invalid column name 'ReportAssignment_stateYearId'.
> ```

I know this is coming from the modelbuilder on ReportAssignment where I create the composite key, because when I comment that out it works OR when I comment out the McoPihpAssignment Collection on the ReportAssignment model it also works. I just have not figured out a way around this error and am also not sure why this error is showing up now, when it works fine for Plan. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

**UPDATE** So I found out it works fine for Plan because Plan does not have any children that is looking for its composite key. So it looks like McoPihpAssignment is looking for the composite key properties reportAssignmentId and stateYearId on ReportAssignment. I found the SQL code generated by EF where it is calling these properties that are triggering the error:

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[stateId] AS [stateId], 
[Project1].[year] AS [year], 
[Project1].[reportAssignmentId] AS [reportAssignmentId], 
[Project1].[stateYearId1] AS [stateYearId1], 
[Project1].[mcoPihpAssignmentId] AS [mcoPihpAssignmentId], 
[Project1].[reportAssignmentId1] AS [reportAssignmentId1], 
[Project1].[ReportAssignment_reportAssignmentId] AS [ReportAssignment_reportAssignmentId], 
[Project1].[ReportAssignment_stateYearId] AS [ReportAssignment_stateYearId]
FROM ( ... )  AS [Project1]
```

Anyway, I think my new question is, is there a way to add or decorate a property on McoPihpAssignment or ReportAssignment model so that it recognizes the composite key I am creating on ReportAssignment in modelbuilder?

Comment: Have you tried, implementing the Left  to right key Implementation on your model Creation?

Comment: Try this first `modelBuilder.Entity().HasRequired(d => d.Administrator).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);` Just rename the Entity just like in your Model. Try to turn of CascadeOnDelete first. If it works fine then you can remove this and move on to `MapLeft` and `MapRight`

Comment: I am not familiar with using left to right key implementation... In terms of testing the code you have above what would d.Administrator refer too, would that be the McoPihpAssignments Collection? Thanks for helping out!

Comment: The best thing I can say Hotmad is I had the same exact problem before. But more tables on what you have currently. The only thing that helped me is understanding the constraint and the reason why you need to create modelBuilder. `http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application` It will tell you why you're having that error and what you can do is first. Remove the CascadeOnDelete. Because EF. will delete datas from other table that has forgn key constraint. Now understanding the modelBuild to

Comment: get around the error. And it will be a great help in the future on how to strategize your model. Not only for Code first, but also on how you can retrieve the data efficiently. You just have to take your time reading this from top to bottom.

Comment: May I ask why do you have a composite key which is also an identity? whats the benefit of the second col?

Comment: So the composite key is part identity and part parent foreign key. The goal to doing this is to get around the nullable error entityframework throws when you try to edit/delete any parent model that has children. So by creating this composite key instead of throwing that error, ef just drops the records when stateYearId is null. Although, what I am realizing is that every time I save the parent it recreates the children records which is not really ideal.